# Select multiple values from a split string in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I see questions about selecting multiple values from an array using JQ, but I have a string that originally I just need the value after the last `/`, which is easily selected:

Input:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-project-1/zones/europe-west1-b/instanceGroups/test-instance-group-1
```

JQ:

```bash
jq -r '.[]|.zone|=split("/")[-1]|"\(.name) \(.zone)"'
```

Output:

```
test-instance-group-1 europe-west1-b
```

However for the actual instances, the zone isn't listed, so must be extracted from the same key `instance`.

Input:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-project-1/zones/europe-west1-b/instances/test-instance-1
```

JQ:

```bash
jq -r '.[]|.instance|=split("/")[-1]|"\(.instance)'
```

Output:

```
test-instance-1
```

However, I also want to extract the zone infomation, from the input as well, which I presume is selected with `=split("/")[-3]` however no matter how I format the request to JQ, I get errors:

```
$ jq -r '.[]|.instance|=split("/")[-1][-3]|"\(.instance)"'
jq: error (at <stdin>:47): Cannot index string with number
```

How can I extract two strings, from the same value/key ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```bash
jq -r '.[].instance | split("/") | "\(.[-1]) \(.[-3])"'
```